# Ways to fake back end with utmost flexibility, given the url string, the parameters, the response code and responses in JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am developing UI in react, and some other team is taking care of the back end. I have only 15% of the the api available at the moment.

I want to fake back end but also have utmost flexibility:

1. URLs including dynamic parts.
2. Allowed HTTP methods
3. Errors(supporting all HTTP status codes)
4. Persisting of payload data for POST, PUT and PATCH requests
5. Automatic and real relation between data of different endpoints,

I am open to using Express.js and Node.js or anything else. I am new to this, so I want the community to guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for what you're talking about the best option would be to use node/express. None of the mocking apps I'm aware of will allow you to cover numbers 4 and 5, but you can likely set up a simple express server that will get the job done.